# Samples of events tcl/tk

Tags: events, tcl, bind, tk-toolkit

Where can I find a list of all the samples of events for the command "bind" in TCL?

```
#For example:
bind .listbox <<ListboxSelect>> {...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various virtual events are documented in each widget's manual page.

Since the virtual events can be defined and configured by any widget, and some virtual events are defined and used internally by widgets, there's no easy way to create a master list.

Comment: The lists on the documentation web pages were made by grepping the source code.